# Difference between "God bless" and "God bless you"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between *God bless* and *God bless you*?

Comment: Please show some research, and add some context to your question.

Comment: The first was said by Red Skelton, the second by the Pope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference, although *God Bless* is more often used as a farewell greeting, and *God bless you* is more often used as an interjection, for example as a way of saying *Thank you* for a favour performed. In the same way, *Bless you!* is used, with exactly the same meaning, to express sympathy when someone sneezes.

They are all informal ways of saying *May the blessings of God be upon you.*

Comment: Saying *bless you* when someone sneezes is of much deeper significance than casual sympathy. It dates from at least AD77, and relates to folklore that believed the soul could be separated from the body during a sneeze. If someone intervened with *bless you* quickly enough it could prevent such a catastrophe. See [God bless you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: They spoke English in 77 AD?